# google map v3, cannot load marks for firefox 26.0(latest version)

Tags: firefox, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

For now we are using google map v3, after we upgraded firefox 26.0, the marks cannot be loaded
I set many alerts and compared them between Chrome and firefox 26.0, I found here is a variable this.ready_ cannot be assigned a value(true) in firefox 26.0 , that is this method cannot be called below

```
MarkerClusterer.prototype.onAdd = function() {
  alert("enter MarkerClusterer.prototype.onAdd!");
  this.setReady_(true);
};
MarkerClusterer.prototype.setReady_ = function(ready) {
  alert("enter setReady!");
  if (!this.ready_) {
    this.ready_ = ready;
    alert("will enter createClusters_() in setReady_");
    this.createClusters_();
  }
};
```

I tried to find where does call onAdd for pinpoint the issue, however, it called by google itself, here is stack call

```
MarkerClusterer.onAdd     MarkerClusterer.js:225
mG                        VM148:1
anonymous function      %7Bmain,places%7D.js:11
```

Thank you by advance!
Jason

Comment: FYI, MarkerClusterer [advanced-example](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/examples/advanced_example.html) works with my latest FF without problems.

Comment: What version of the MarkerClusterer are you using? [This page using the MarkerClusterer](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/tanagerproductions_testmapA.html) works for me in FF 26.0.

Comment: Thank you Anto and geocodezip,

Comment: thank you Anto and geocodezip, for now I am using version 1.0 of MarkerClusterer.js, I compared this version with latest one, there is no big changing, I feel that the issue mainly focus on why this MarkerClusterer.prototype.onAdd() function cannot be called in firefox 26.0 sometimes(just 1 or 2 times it works), and when this method should be called, please advise, many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue, the problem was from MarkerClusterer.js, someone commentted these 2 lines below leads to this issue(just comment them off will be ok), hope it is also helpful for others.
    in     MarkerClusterer.js
    MarkerClusterer.prototype.setupStyles_ = function() {
        if (this.styles_.length) {
          return;
        }
       // for (var i = 0, size; size = this.sizes[i]; i++) {
        this.styles_.push({
        url: this.imagePath_ + '.' + this.imageExtension_,
        height: 36,
        width: 43
       // });
    }